# Akka-Camel integration module example using Java API

Tags: rest, apache-camel, akka, java

Can someone point me to an example of using Akka Camel integration module - using the Java API. I have a use case where a REST service is called that would start some Akka Actors in parallel to process the request and then each would push partial results to the web browser (Comet style). I saw one example [here](http://akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.2/modules/camel.html#cometd) but unfortunately I don't know scala and I would like to see this in Java.

Has anyone translated this examples into Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the examples for Akka Camel show both the Scala version of the code, and then the Java version: http://akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.2/modules/camel.html

Comment: Not a valid link anymore

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you can get all tutorials, samples with **Typesafe reactive platform** which you can get from Akka website. The latest documentation for **Akka Java** and **Scala** is always available [here](http://akka.io/docs/,). It contains everything, including **Akka Extensions** like **Akka Camel**.

Furthermore, if you don't want to use **Typesafe reactive platform** application you can browse [Git-Hub Akka Samples](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-samples,)

PS: unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to add more than 2 links to my answer...